# Why does SELinux (with Enforcing=1) allow binding to low (or any) ports, by default?

Tags: selinux, port

I assume that Selinux defaults, based on the documentation, mandate that basically all port operations would be blocked and logged as AVCs.

I have an SELinux enforcing enabled VM, created with Centos7 out of the box.

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             mls
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      31
```

However, I can start a webserver and bind it to port 1.

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer 1
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 1 ...
```

Im assuming SElinux , with enforcing and no other modifications on a fresh OS would actually limit access to these sorts of operations (im just using port 1 as an example of how severe a security violation can be, because in general I thought *at least* low number ports would be blocked by default via selinux).

Comment: I'd additionally note that root privileges are required to bind on ports under 1024, and you're specifically running the python script under `sudo`.

Comment: Yes, thats part of the point :) I want to test that SELinux is preventing me, even as root, from doing the wrong thing.

Comment: @jayunit100 Then you would need to configure confined users (without transition to administrative/unconfined domains), which would prevent users gaining privileges even with `sudo` (confined root).

Answer (score 1):

SELinux configuration (reference policy) includes unconfined types, and by default users are in unconfined domain (`unconfined_t`). For unconfined processes (and users who can start unconfined processes) there are very few restrictions. A process running in unconfined domain has almost the same privileges as a process would have on non-SELinux system.

The other type of domains are confined domains, which have strict rules what a process running in such domain is allowed to do.

[RedHat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Targeted_Policy-Confined_and_Unconfined_Users) has some details and examples if you want to configure your system with confined SELinux users.

Comment: Interesting ,so , I ran `semanage login -l` and got *no* output.  If my user is unconfined, shouldn't it still have an entry under the selinux users mapping?

Comment: Actually, so, i found out that yes, default users are unconfined, just like root . ```[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo id -Z
unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ id -Z
unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023```